# Tile Engine Collision

Tags: c#, xna, collision, tile

Okay, so, I am making a small tile-based digging game, now I want to do collision. How would I go about doing this correctly? I know how to check if the player collides with a tile, but I don't know how to actually make the player stop when it hits a wall.

[image]

This is the game, I got 20x20 tiles here.

This is the code I'm using atm:

```
            foreach (Tile tiles in allTiles)
        {
            if (ply.rect.Intersects(tiles.rect))
            {
                if (tiles.ID != -1 && tiles.ID != 1)
                {
                    if (ply.X > tiles.X)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Right part.");
                        ply.X = tiles.pos.X + 30;
                    }

                    if (ply.X <= tiles.X)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Left part.");
                        ply.X  = tiles.pos.X - 30;
                    }

                    if (ply.Y > tiles.Y) 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Bottom part.");
                        ply.Y = tiles.pos.Y + 30;
                    }

                    if (ply.Y <= tiles.Y) 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Upper part.");
                        ply.Y = tiles.pos.Y - 30;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you making [`Terraria`](http://terraria.org/)?

Comment: @Marty Wallace: Well, I'm making somekind of clone, yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of collision detection are you using?

If your using Rectangles and the '.intersects' method you can always declare a bool to make sure your character is touching the floor. If he isn't you apply a Gravity Vector to make it fall to the next Tile with a different Rectangle so when he hits it he's going to stop falling.

If you want to block him from side to side just test to see which side of the rectangle he is touching and block him from moving on the 'X' axis.
E.g if he is going right and intersects with the left part of a rectangle, block is 'GoingRight' movement.

```
    if(myCharacterRectangle.Intersects(tileRectangle)
    {

        if(myCharacterPosition.X > (tilePosition.X)
       {
         //You know the character hits the Right part of the tile.
       }

        if(mycharacterPosition.X <= tilePosition.X)
       {
         //You know the character hits the Left Part of the tile.
       }

    }
```

And same goes for the Position.Y if you want to test the Top or Bottom.

If you want to use Pixel by Pixel collision detection using Matrices I know a good tutorial [here](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/series2d.php).
The detection will return a 'Vector2(-1,-1)' if there is no collision. 
If there is a one the method will return the coordinates of the collisions which makes it even easier to determine what part of the tile your character is touching.

Hope this helps. Good Luck with your game.

Comment: I saw question similar to yours.
Maybe this is what you need
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/167529-xna-tile-collision-detection/

Comment: I tried this left and right hitting of the tile but it isn't working, it kept saying that it was hitting the left side, no matter where I was. The collision is annoying to do because it hits so many blocks at one time.

Comment: Ok i'll try it in a few minutes to see where the problem is

Comment: Just replace the : if(myCharacterPosition.X >= (tilePosition.X + tileTexture.Width)) I'll change it in my answer

Comment: so I changed the operator >= to a simple > and removed the +tileTexture part this should solve the Always hitting left problem.
And yes collisions are always annoying. Just make sure all your rectangle are the right size and check that double collisions won't break your logic.
E.g If you do a block breaker game and the collision makes a rebound effect Position * -1 hitting two blocks at the same time would do Position *-1 twice so Position *1 which is not at all what we want.

Comment: The idea is to check from the side you *were* on before you move into the tile and collide with it. With that information, you're able to easily work out which side of the tile you should be testing for a collision against.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this question as answered if you found what you were looking for :)

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk I just got one more small problem, how would I measure how deep the player is in the tile so I can move him back that distance? I've got the left-right and top-down collision working, it's just that now.

Comment: You dont need to know how deep he is since you found out where he entered the tile.

Comment: What i mean by that is if he entered by the left side, and went too far into the tile just set the player position .x to the position .x of the left side of the tile(where he should have stopped).

Comment: If you mean how will he get to the next tile if you dont know where he is in the present tile its even easier. On the x axis its not a problem since hes moving manually. For the Y axis this is where you implement your gravity vector. Your character is always falling except when he touche a tile. This way if he is on top of a tile and breaks it hes automaticly going to fall on the next tile now matter where he was in the other tile

Comment: What i'd do from here is limit the number of collisions per frame to 1.
When the game enters the Update set a counter to 0.
When you have a collisions apply +1 to your counter and add '&& myCounter == 0' to all your conditions to make sure you won't have more than one collision per frame.
Then when you come back into update the counter is reset to 0 and youre ready for a new collision.
Don't forget the game is passing through the update 60 times per second so you won't see the difference